# Is it possible to share an Open Graph video on Facebook that both plays and links back to my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, facebook-opengraph

I am hosting videos on a website, and have created Open Graph video tags so that when a page like example.com/video/my-new-video is shared on Facebook that video can be played in the Facebook newsfeed, but there's no link back to example.com/video/my-new-video.

The Open Graph tags in this case look like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My New Video" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="This is my new video about sharing videos" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />           
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/video/my-new-video/poster-image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/video/my-new-video/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/video/my-new-video/video-file.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://example.com/video/my-new-video/video-file.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />       
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="720" />
```

If I remove the og:video URL that points to the SWF to play the video I get the video's image and description with a link to example.com/video/my-new-video but it's not possible to play the video in the Facebook newsfeed.

The Open Graph tags in this case look like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My New Video" /> 
<meta property="og:description" content="This is my new video about sharing videos" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxxxxxxxxxxxx" />           
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/video/my-new-video/poster-image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/video/my-new-video/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://example.com/video/my-new-video/iframe-embed.php" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://example.com/video/my-new-video/iframe-embed.php" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html" />       
<meta property="og:video:width" content="1280" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="720" />
```

Is there a way to both let the video play in the Facebook feed and link back to the page it's on?